# Error with downloading image as data url

Tags: javascript, data-url

So, i was doing a link to download an image from a data url(a LARGE one):

```
<a download='fileName' href="data:image/png;base64,/9j/4WSsRX...">something</a>
```

However, whenever i try to click in that link i receive an error telling me some net problems.

I have make a fiddle test, but its LARGE(15mb of text) and it will take sometime to load:

https://jsfiddle.net/jjydp1ek/

As the jsfiddle is hard to load, i added a file in mediafire:
http://www.mediafire.com/download/p85y1g442ne9v6m/new++7.html

The test is an image with the same data url value as the link, the image is visible, however i see that the option to open image in a new tab on chrome isn't working.

I do it with canvas in ie 11 and is failing too

Questions:

It is ever possible to make it work with the download link as it is now?

Is there a limit size with the data url to download a file, which is?

How do i do to make the user able to download that image?

Also, ask questions here, or correct any error in the text you see if you think its not understandable.

Thanks.

Comment: Can we get the error?

Comment: @Jezzabeanz there it is the fiddle with the image, you can modify it to transform that image into a link, and changing the src to href. You can see you cannot right click open in a new tab, and you can try that from the chrome debug tools and it will be a black screen.

Comment: Can you make a smaller fiddle? My laptop fan starts going wild when I try to go to your fiddle. For example purposes it doesn't need to be a valid image, any data will do.

Comment: i will try to add a pastebin so you can test it in your home, or see how is the data url. (it's ok for me to comment answers here?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a 70Mb broadband and a powerhouse of a PC and that JS fiddle won't even open.

I don't think it's feasible to have a 15MB encoded string, since that has to be downloaded onto the page each time on every visit. I would try the following:

- Optimise the image, you could incorporate [gulp-imagemin](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-imagemin) if you have/want to have Gulp for a build system. I think there are alternatives for Grunt if you wanted to go that way.
- Store the file on the server and just place a link to the path, this is the preferred solution.

In response to your questions

The limit:

> **Length limitations**
>
> Although Mozilla supports data URIs of essentially
> unlimited length, browsers are not required to support any particular
> maximum length of data. For example, the Opera 11 browser limits data
> URIs to around 65000 characters.

Source: [data URIs - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs)

**Downloading**

The above suggestion on optimising the image as small as you can get without losing quality if that's a concern. Try it then. If not, it's not a problem to give the user a link to the image / display it on the page. The user can right click and save.

**Note**

By the time I finished writing this response JSFiddle timed out.

Comment: which browser were you using? iam using chrome and is loading it in 20 minutes... 
Still thanks for telling me that, it's not a solution right now. I have uploaded a file in mediafire with the code to "download" the image.

Comment: @Gaunt I'm using Chrome Version 50.0.2661.102, Windows 10.

Comment: Exactly same version, windows 7 no idea :P

Comment: There is no solution, it's just wrong to try to do this, i made a download link from a C# code wherever i needed the full  image.